# How to refresh a TextView from another class?

Tags: java, android-studio

I get this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback
>   android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

```
public class AdaptadorCarrito extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCarrito.ViewHolderCarrito> {

ArrayList<CarritoVo> listaCarrito;
AdaptadorCarrito adapter;
RecyclerView.Adapter madapter;
int i = 1;

public AdaptadorCarrito(ArrayList<CarritoVo> listaCarrito) {
    this.listaCarrito = listaCarrito;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderCarrito onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_carrito, null, false);
    final ViewHolderCarrito myHolder = new ViewHolderCarrito(view);
    final CafeteriaDB cafeteriaDB = new CafeteriaDB(parent.getContext());

    myHolder.item_list_carrito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int newPosition = myHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            cafeteriaDB.eliminarProducto(myHolder.etiNombre.getText().toString(), myHolder.etiInfo.getText().toString());
            eliminarProducto(newPosition);
            // i++;
            // Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Producto Eliminado "+i+" eliminado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CarritoCompras obj = new CarritoCompras();
            TextView tv = obj.getTextView(); //Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));
        }

    });
    return myHolder;
}

private void eliminarProducto(int position) {
    listaCarrito.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderCarrito holder, int position) {
    CarritoVo positions = listaCarrito.get(position);
    holder.etiNombre.setText(listaCarrito.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.etiPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(listaCarrito.get(position).getPrecio()));
    holder.etiInfo.setText(listaCarrito.get(position).getInfo());
    holder.etiCantidades.setText(String.valueOf(listaCarrito.get(position).getCantidad()));
    holder.etiFoto.setImageBitmap(positions.getFoto());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return listaCarrito.size();
    return (listaCarrito == null) ? 0 : listaCarrito.size();
}

public class ViewHolderCarrito extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    LinearLayout item_list_carrito;
    TextView etiNombre, etiPrecio, etiInfo, etiCantidades, txtTotalB, txtTotalF;
    ImageView etiFoto;

    public ViewHolderCarrito(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item_list_carrito = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_carrito_item);
        etiFoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotoC);
        etiNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreC);
        etiPrecio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioC);
        etiInfo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.infoC);
        etiCantidades = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidadC);
    }
}
}
```

*Activity*

```
public class CarritoCompras extends AppCompatActivity implements Carrito.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

TextView txtTotalF;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito_compras);
    CafeteriaDB db = new CafeteriaDB(this);

    getTextView();

    txtTotalF = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalF);

    txtTotalF.setText(String.valueOf(db.totalFilas()));

}

public TextView getTextView(){
    TextView txtTotalB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalB); //Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    return txtTotalB;
}



@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

Comment: why are you creating instance every time declare at once

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following way

**Step 1:**

Load TextView at only once

```
  TextView txtTotalB; // declare class level
```

inside onCreate()

```
 txtTotalB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalB);
```

**Step 2:**

create method

```
public TextView getTextView(){
    return txtTotalB
}
```

**Step 3:**

inside your adapter class access your activity method like below

```
TextView tv = ((CarritoCompras)context).getTextView();
tv.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));   // now here you done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interfaces for communication.

Create an interface as shown below:

```
public interface RecyclerItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String text);
}
```

In your adapter class, create declare a variable of type `RecyclerItemClickListener` and modify the Adapter's constructor to accept an instance of 'RecyclerItemClickListener' as a parameter. i.e Modify your Adapter class as shown below:

```
public class AdaptadorCarrito extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorCarrito.ViewHolderCarrito> {

RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener; //Here we are declaring a variable of the created interface
ArrayList<CarritoVo> listaCarrito;
AdaptadorCarrito adapter;
RecyclerView.Adapter madapter;
int i = 1;

//Modifying the constructor to initialize the above declared listener
public AdaptadorCarrito(ArrayList<CarritoVo> listaCarrito, RecyclerItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listaCarrito = listaCarrito;
    this.recyclerItemClickListener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderCarrito onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_carrito, null, false);
    final ViewHolderCarrito myHolder = new ViewHolderCarrito(view);
    final CafeteriaDB cafeteriaDB = new CafeteriaDB(parent.getContext());

    myHolder.item_list_carrito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int newPosition = myHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            cafeteriaDB.eliminarProducto(myHolder.etiNombre.getText().toString(), myHolder.etiInfo.getText().toString());
            eliminarProducto(newPosition);
            // i++;
            // Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Producto Eliminado "+i+" eliminado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CarritoCompras obj = new CarritoCompras();
            /*TextView tv = obj.getTextView(); //Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));*/

       //Here we are passing the test to be displayed in the textview to your activity     
       recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));
        }

    });
    return myHolder;
}

private void eliminarProducto(int position) {
    listaCarrito.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderCarrito holder, int position) {
    CarritoVo positions = listaCarrito.get(position);
    holder.etiNombre.setText(listaCarrito.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.etiPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(listaCarrito.get(position).getPrecio()));
    holder.etiInfo.setText(listaCarrito.get(position).getInfo());
    holder.etiCantidades.setText(String.valueOf(listaCarrito.get(position).getCantidad()));
    holder.etiFoto.setImageBitmap(positions.getFoto());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //return listaCarrito.size();
    return (listaCarrito == null) ? 0 : listaCarrito.size();
}

public class ViewHolderCarrito extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    LinearLayout item_list_carrito;
    TextView etiNombre, etiPrecio, etiInfo, etiCantidades, txtTotalB, txtTotalF;
    ImageView etiFoto;

    public ViewHolderCarrito(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item_list_carrito = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_carrito_item);
        etiFoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotoC);
        etiNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreC);
        etiPrecio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioC);
        etiInfo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.infoC);
        etiCantidades = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cantidadC);
    }
}
}
```

Now in your Activity where you will be instantiating the `AdaptadorCarrito` Object, you need to pass the instance of `RecyclerItemClickListener` as parameter to the Adapter's constructor.

Example:

```
AdaptadorCarrito adapter = new AdaptadorCarrito(listaCarrito , new RecyclerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String text) {
                 //In here you can set your TextView's text
                 TextView txtTotalB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalB);
                 txtTotalB.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error on the line: recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for answering, I was able to solve my problem, which was to update a text view that was in an activity but that needed the help of an event that was in another class to do so.**

*first adding an activity in the constructor of the adapter*

```
  Activity activity;

public AdaptadorCarrito(ArrayList<CarritoVo> nlistaCarrito, Activity nactivity) {
    nListCarrito = nlistaCarrito;
    this.activity = nactivity;
}
```

*Then calling TextView the this way:*

```
 public ViewHolderCarrito onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_carrito,null,false);
    final ViewHolderCarrito myHolder = new ViewHolderCarrito(view);
    final CafeteriaDB cafeteriaDB = new CafeteriaDB(parent.getContext());;
    final CarritoCompras carrito = new CarritoCompras();
   ---->final TextView txtTotalB = (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.totalB);
    txtTotalB.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));

    myHolder.item_list_carrito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int newPosition = myHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            cafeteriaDB.eliminarProducto(myHolder.etiNombre.getText().toString(), myHolder.etiInfo.getText().toString());
            eliminarProducto(newPosition);
           Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Producto Eliminado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      ----->  txtTotalB.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.getTotal()));
        }

    });
    return myHolder;
}
```

*and finally creating an instance of the adapter in the activity*

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito_compras);
    ArrayList<CarritoVo> nLlistaCarrito = null;

    ------>AdaptadorCarrito adapter = new AdaptadorCarrito(nLlistaCarrito,this);

    CafeteriaDB cafeteriaDB = new CafeteriaDB(this);

    TextView txtTotalB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalB);
    txtTotalB.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.totalFilas()));

    TextView txtTotalF = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalF);
    txtTotalF.setText(String.valueOf(cafeteriaDB.totalFilas()));
}
```